# How to replace the words with certain pattern in a file with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, database, unix, sed

I know how to replace a word with sed. Using

```
sed -i 's/[old_text]\b/[new_text]/g'
```

could replace old_text with new_text.

What I want to do is to replace nchar(10) or nchar (10) or nchar ( 10)... with char(10) in a DB schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Human
(
    ID int,
    Name nchar(10)  --> should be replace with char(10)
);
```

The format is quite hard to be determined.

I don't know how to set the sed regular expression to archive this.

Comment: Did you attempt to read the _fantastic_ manual <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make spaces optional everywhere:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\<nchar *( *\([0-9]*\) *)/char(\1)/g' file.sql
```

- `\<` is used for word boundary.

Comment: Can you suggest me where to search for the definition of `\<`? I didn't see the usage of `\<` in the GNU sed manual.

Comment: This means word boundary and this is Posix syntax. I will try to find an online reference for this.

Comment: Thanks. I found it on http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html . It seems that I can use \b, \B, \< and \> as well

Comment: Yes that's right but older sed versions don't support `\b` for boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Or rather you  can open the file in vi and use following in vi cmd mode

```
%s/nchar/char/g
```

This replaces in entire file at once

All occurrences of nchar will be replaced in one go.

And to check before replacing all

```
%s/nchar/char/gc
```

y for yes

n for not replacing

a for replacing rest all

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and extended regex `-r` (for clarity). Also `-i` means "inplace" so no need to create a different output file

```
sed -i sqlfile -r -e "s/nchar\s*\(\s*([0-9]+)\s*\)/char(\1)/g"
```